# Can't convert string to date in Java, wrong timezone after conversion

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, date-comparison

I have an array of `Strings` with the dates e.g.:

- *Tue, 09 Feb 2016 14:07:00 GMT*;
- *Tue, 09 Feb 2016 19:55:00 GMT*.

Now I want to find the most recent date on this list. In order to do that, I try to deserialize these strings to `java.util.Date` objects and after that compare them.

The code sample of `java.util.Date` object generation:

```js
strDate = "Tue, 09 Feb 2016 14:07:00 GMT";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

Date date;
try {

    date = format.parse(strDate);

    //Result: Tue Feb 09 16:07:00 IST 2016
    System.out.println("Result: " + date.toString());

} catch(ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My questions:

1. Why is the result in *IST 2016* time zone and not in *GMT*? What does the *IST 2016* stand for? Is it *India Standard Time* or *Irish Standard Time* or *Israel Standard Time*?
2. The initial string is in `EEE, dd MMM` format, the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is also in this format, thus, why the result is in `EEE, MMM dd` format?
3. How can get a `java.util.Date` object in the same timezone as the initial string, in my case — *GMT*?
4. Is the approach I'm using to find the most recent date in the list is OK or there is more convenient/modern way to do that in Java 8, e.g., with the usage of `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Use a `DateFormat.format(...)`, not `Date.toString()`, to print a `Date`. The latter prints it in the JVM default timezone; the former prints it out in whichever timezone you configure on the instance.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I check the value of `date` in debugger even there the date is in `IST 2016` and not in `GMT`.

Comment: `Date`s don't have a specific "timezone". The only timezone they have is that of the JVM. You must have some environment variable or preference somewhere specifying that IST should be used by default in the JVM.

Comment: BTW, I that's "Israel Standard Time", not "Indian Standard Time".

Comment: @AndyTurner, `Israel Standard Time` is more logical for my case and, probably, it's a correct explanation. The reason I decided that's `Indian Standard Time`: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist but there is also http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-israel.

Comment: And [Irish Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ist#Time_zones). This is why three-letter abbreviations for timezones should be avoided.

Comment: As suggested, avoid such 3-4 letter codes as they are neither standardized nor unique. See [this list of proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). By the way, if it were India time you could tell by the half-hour; India uses an offset of five and a half hours, `+05:30`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are relying to `Date.toString()` to print your date when you should format it to a `String` with a formatter. What you are seeing is just the default pattern of `Date.toString()`. What you must keep in mind is that a `Date` does not have a timezone. You are seeing the output with the IST timezone, this must be because the current locale for the JVM is set to some specific locale for which the timezone name is `"IST"`.

With regard to your point 4, yes, you can do it much cleaner with Java Time API introduced in Java 8. You can create a `List` of your strings to parse, create a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse it, and keep the maximum date value.

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("Tue, 09 Feb 2016 14:07:00 GMT", "Tue, 09 Feb 2016 19:55:00 GMT");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    ZonedDateTime maxDate = dates.stream()
                                 .map(s -> ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter))
                                 .max(ZonedDateTime::compareTo)
                                 .get(); // or .orElse(null)
    
    System.out.println(maxDate);
}
```

This code is using a `ZonedDateTime` to keep the time-zone of the incoming strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer seems to be set to `IST`. To force `GMT` output, import `java.util.TimeZone` and do this in your `try` block:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
date = format.parse(strDate);

System.out.println("Result: " + format.format(date));
```